# Subversion URL bash completion

Tags: macos, bash, svn

I found the below script and sourced it correctly, and it successfully bash completes my commands, but isn't working for my URLs.   I'm using OSX Snow Leopard and 3.2.48 and I've been using the normal bash-completion  1.2 for months now.  I'm using SVN client 1.6.15 and we're using svn+ssh for SVN access.

http://labs.silverorange.com/archive/2004/december/bashcompletion

Any tips how to get it working

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried Apache's version? This can be either sourced in .bashrc or added to bash_completion

https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/subversion/trunk/tools/client-side/bash_completion